# What is the name of the drum sound where the hi-hat creates a "riser" by opening after being hit?

Tags: technique, terminology, drum-kits

There's a very common drumming technique, usually towards the end of a bar, where the hi-hat is hit while being opened creating a "riser" sound.

I had always thought it was called a "fill," but it's really just a very simple version of a fill.  What is this sound/technique called?

Comment: Open hi hat? Not everything has a name.

Comment: Good question! We like labels, so if there isn't one, maybe there should be! Although there are various hi-hat sounds from hard shut through 'half open', to completely open, let alone 'hit it closed, and open it straight away'. +1.

Comment: Open hat, and closed hat are both things I can easily search for on any sound library.  I would be really surprised if this doesn't have a name, given how widely used and introductory it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the name of this drums "disco" rhythm/technique?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/what-is-the-name-of-this-drums-disco-rhythm-technique)

Comment: Not sure, but it's definitely not "[drum riser](https://soimagescdn.azureedge.net/productimage/Intellistage/ISG-ISMDRUM6413.jpg)", which is something else entirely.

Comment: @ojs, that is definitely very close.  There is a subtle difference between `open-close-open-close` and an "opening" sound in isolation.  I've heard songs that have that opening sound alone, and it doesn't sound like an open hat hit.  I think this "opening" sound is a byproduct of the `open-close` pattern, but they're probably so related that differentiating between the two is pedantic in most scenarios.

Comment: @SephReed the point is, it doesn't seem to name beyond "open hi-hat" or at least nobody here has heard it. My best guess is that after coming up with "pataflafla" and ""flamadiddle-diddle", the mysterious cabal that invents the names decided it's getting too silly and stopped.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be describing this sound:

I would describe this simply as "gradually open hi-hat" / "slowly open hi-hat"

Answer (score 0):

It's just called "open hi-hat". And yes, it is often used as simple type of drum fill.

Here is a short lesson on how to play open hi-hat:

---

Open hi-hat is usually represented in notation by a small circle (o) above a regular hi-hat note.  Closing the hi-hat is then represented with a small plus sign (+) above the note.  Once the hi-hats are closed the plus sign is not written.